# file not found error with python, no error in cmd

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ghostscript

I've made a python script for windows to print each file in a directory. To do that, i use ghostscript and gsprint.

When i launch the script, there is an error `WindowsError: [error2] file not found`

If i launch the same command line in cmd, there is no error and the pdf is printed...

here is my script:

```
for f_name in files_in_dir:
    fullpath_file = os.path.join(base_print, path_print_source, f_name)
    carrier = f_name.split('-')[0]
    new_path = os.path.join(base_print, carrier + '_printed')
    new_fullpath_file = os.path.join(new_path, f_name)

    print Tools.format_txt("traitement du fichier %s" % f_name)
    print Tools.format_txt("traitement du fichier %s" % f_name, carrier)

    p = subprocess.Popen(['gsprint', '-printer', printer,'-dPDFFitPage', fullpath_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    if out:
        print Tools.format_txt(out)
    if err:
        print Tools.format_txt(err, level="error")

    print Tools.format_txt("fichier %s envoyé pour impression" % f_name, carrier)

    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
        os.makedirs(new_path)
    os.rename(fullpath_file, new_fullpath_file)
```

the generated path for the file is : `C:\Users\GREG\Downloads\DHL-575555338523255087006833669.pdf`

traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-print.py", line 95, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())  # si le script est utilis├® comme un module, on n'ex├®cute pas le script
  File "python-print.py", line 61, in main
    p = subprocess.Popen(['gsprint', '-printer', printer,'-dPDFFitPage', fullpath_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable
```

I'm using windows 10 with python 2.7

Comment: How do you launch the script? Is `gsprint` in PATH?

Comment: yes gsprint is in the path

Comment: the script is launched with idle -- edit : with cmd it-'s the same

Comment: Can you give the complete traceback?

Comment: Shouldn't one need to use `gsprint.exe` under windows?

Comment: does not change, even if i use full path for gsprint

Comment: Is it possible that you have an error in your full path for gsprint? Can you show it here? You could also try `shell=True` because you said it works fine if you type gsprint in the shell, but normally it shouldn't fix our error.

Comment: @syntonym In that case one should provide a command line as a  string (and be aware that the shell may do expansion on that)...

Comment: @skyking On windows arguments in a list will not be interpreted as arguments for the shell but are seemingly passed into the shell. Generally you are right of course. But because Crozet said `gsprint` would work in a cmd I thought it might be worth a try.

Comment: problem solved, the file not found was gsprint and the problem was solved by moving it in a directory without spaces. Thank you for your time

Comment: @skyking, `CreateProcess` appends ".exe" to the name, by way of the `lpExtension` parameter of the [`SearchPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527) function. Similarly the loader appends ".DLL" for a `LoadLibrary` call (but the loader uses its own search routine, `LdrpSearchPath`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, i managed to solve the problem :

Gsprint was installed in `c:\program files` i moved it and installed in `c:\GSP` so a path without spaces and it worked fine.

Comment: There is no problem finding a file in a `PATH` directory that has spaces. Did you mistakenly wrap the `PATH` entry in double quotes? cmd.exe is the only program that ignores quotes in `PATH` (sometimes) because it implements its own search function (inherited from its OS/2 beginnings). Almost everything else in Windows, including `CreateProcess`, relies directly or indirectly on the `SearchPath` API, which tries to list the directory with the quotes as literally part of the path. Of course that fails, and it quietly skips to the next entry.

Comment: Yes the path was between quotes (only the path to gsprint, not the entiere string). it was generated by windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "it was generated by Windows"? Do you mean the installer for ghostscript added this bogus `PATH` entry?

Comment: on windows 10 when you edit the path, it opens a window with a list of all directories and if you want to add one, you just browse to the directory and click add. it is not a basic text edit like on windows 7 (pic here : http://www.comtek4u.com/sites/default/files/images/windows-10-new-environment-variables-editor.jpg)

Comment: I've used that new dialog. It's not used for just `PATH`, but any variable that has a semicolon-delimited list of 2 or more fully-qualified paths. The quotes it adds around a path in the dialog box aren't actually added to the final `PATH`, at least not for me.